# Sinch App-to-App Calling: Failed to create certificate request

Tags: ios, sinch

I am following SinchCallingPushWithService project. When used via sample project supplied its working fine. When integrated within my project with same keys it keep giving this error

**Failed to create certificate request: -8187**

**Failed to generate certificate:failed create certificate**

When I start call there is no sound. I have rightly configured all three certificates at sinch dashboard and working fine with the above mentioned supplied sample.

Answer (score 0):

What `userId` are you passing to the SinchService? (How long is it? Is it ASCII only, or does it contain multibyte unicode characters?)

(The error is not related to APNS push certificates. The error you are seeing is related to the internal generation of a X.509 certificate which the peer will use to encrypt it's media traffic (SRTP).

Comment: its my fone number that i am passing as user id +9234559XXXX all numbers. Also during call there is no voice? Can this error possibly linked with voice issue?

Comment: I removed "+" and now its working fine. Printing another error "Unknown signaling method UNDEFINED"

Comment: Naxir, can you update the question with the new log? Or if you prefer you can mail it in to support@sinch.com